# Error code 0x80004005 when executing package as a scheduled job

Tags: ssis

The error message is:

> POSTGRES dm_genders_d failed validation and returned error code
>   0x80004005.

I've seen several references to this almost assuredly being a permissions issue, which sounds right to me, but I have been completely unable to identify the relevant permissions.

The Postgres connection is using ODBC.  The package is moving data from PostgreSQL to SQL Server.  Currently both 32bit and 64bit drivers exist, but I haven't seen how to choose between them.

I have made all of the recommended changes to 32 bit for the job.

We are using Windows Authentication.

I've set up a proxy to execute the job as my user.

None of this has alleviated this error.

UPDATE:  Yes, the 32 bit data source has been defined, and it is being used.

Comment: You are going the 32bit route but have not set up your ODBC connection on the server that host the SQL Agent?

Comment: Have you tried creating a DSN using the 32 bit driver and then giving it a shot?

Answer (score 0):

I had this error and I could solve it by Add ODBC connection in the "**system DSN**" instead of "**User DSN**" tab.

**Start**   >   **ODBC Data Sources**

[image]

Also I ran package with 32-bit runtime

for this: right click on your job in SQL Server Agent > properties > steps > edit

in the window that appear (Job Step Properties) you can set 32-bit runtime. (below picture)
[image]